# Calling a Procedure with name of Table as argument and assigning same datatype to variables as in Table in PL / SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

following is the code. What I am doing here is passing the table_name as argument (I don't know how to pass it, I just searched it on stackoverflow and other websites, and came up with this solution. Apparently it is a way to pass the table dynamically however, I don't know the logic behind) to a procedure and then using that table to get the maximum and minimum salary of employees from employee table. 
Following is the Procedure code (it works well)

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE MINMAX (Employee in varchar2)
IS
LOWEST emp.SAL%TYPE;
HIGHEST emp.SAL%TYPE;
BEGIN
execute immediate 'SELECT MIN(SAL) from ' || Employee into LOWEST;
execute immediate 'SELECT MAX(SAL) from ' || Employee into HIGHEST;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MINIMUM SALARY is : ' || Lowest  );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MAXIMUM SALARY is : ' || Highest  );
END;
/
```

And this is how I tried to execute it, but it gave me error.

```
Begin 
MINMAX(emp); 
END; 
/
```

This is the error I got

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'EMP' not allowed in this context
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Table with name of "emp" does exist, but I don't know how to pass that as an argument to the procedure..

Secondly, if you look at the procedure code, I had to declare the variables like this,

```
LOWEST emp.SAL%TYPE;
HIGHEST emp.SAL%TYPE;
```

Can I change these to the datatype in accordance to the passed table (as argument)? Like this,

```
LOWEST Employee.SAL%TYPE;
HIGHEST Employee.SAL%TYPE;
```

I tried doing this, and it also gave me an error on this.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQL Server? Please remove the incorrect tags.

Comment: Hint:  `'emp'` is the name of the table.

Comment: MINIMAX or MINMAX

Comment: Yes, 'emp' solves the problem. Thank you, @GordonLinoff
But can I know that do we always pass tables as "varchars" in parameters in the procedures? Also, how can I give the datatype of the variables I declare within the Procedure in accordance to the datatype of the columns of the table "being passed" as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below procedure to achieve the declaration of variables based on table input

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Minmax (employee IN VARCHAR2)
    IS
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DECLARE 
    HIGHEST '||employee||'.SAL%TYPE;
    LOWEST  '||employee||
        '.SAL%TYPE;
    BEGIN
    SELECT MIN(SAL) INTO LOWEST from '|| employee||
        ';
    SELECT MAX(SAL) into HIGHEST from '|| employee||' ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''MINIMUM SALARY is : '' || Lowest  );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''MAXIMUM SALARY is : ''|| Highest );
    END;';
    END;
```

Execute it using

```
      Begin 
      MINMAX('emp');  
      END;
```

Output

```
   MINIMUM SALARY is : 800
   MAXIMUM SALARY is : 5000
```

You can also pass the column_name as a parameter like the below

```
        CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Minmax (table_name IN VARCHAR2,column_name in varchar2)
        IS
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DECLARE 
        HIGHEST '||table_name||'.'||column_name||'%TYPE;
        LOWEST  '||table_name||'.'||column_name||'%TYPE;
        BEGIN
        SELECT MIN('||column_name||') INTO LOWEST from '|| table_name||
            ';
        SELECT MAX('||column_name||') into HIGHEST from '|| table_name||' ;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''MINIMUM '||column_name||' is : '' || Lowest  );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''MAXIMUM '||column_name||' is : ''|| Highest );
        END;';
        END;
```

Execute it using

```
  BEGIN
  Minmax('emp','sal');
  end;
```

Output is:-

```
MINIMUM sal is : 800
MAXIMUM sal is : 5000
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your input parameter is `varchar2`.

So call the procedure like this:

```
Begin 
MINMAX('emp');  -- varchar2
END; 
/
```

Comment: Thank you! That solves the issue. 
But can I know that do we always pass tables as "varchars" in parameters in the procedures?
Also, how can I give the datatype of the variables I declare within the Procedure in accordance to the datatype of the columns of the table "being passed" as parameter?

Comment: You have declared the input parameter as VARCHAR2 in the procedure so you need to pass the table name as VARCHAR2. second, the variable datatype can not be the dynamic.

Comment: The variable datatype can be dynamic ,please refer my answer